# Issue with InApp purchase in Sandbox mode: SKProductsRequest delegate returns inconsistent response

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

When requesting for in-app auto renewable subscription products from apple, I sometimes get valid products but most of the times I get invalidProductIdentifiers in SKProductsResponse object. I wrote a small piece of code to verify this inconsistency in response:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self getProductsFromApple];
}

-(void)getProductsFromApple{
    SKProductsRequest *_productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"2"]];
    [_productRequest setDelegate:self];
    [_productRequest start];

}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

    NSLog(@"Invalid %@", response.invalidProductIdentifiers);
    NSLog(@"Valid %@", response.products);

    if (response.invalidProductIdentifiers && [response.invalidProductIdentifiers isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count) {
        [self getProductsFromApple];
    }
}
```

This sometimes succeeds after n calls to apple server.Our team has escalated the issue to apple, we are waiting for there response.
Has anyone faced this issue, kindly suggest how you were able to test in-apps payment ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue. What did Apple say? Thanks.

Comment: @TodorK. yes it is resolved now, we are now getting valid products in first request itself.

Comment: @Say2Manuj we are with the same problem. How did you solved it?

Comment: @RicardoBarroso: It got resolved after a day without making any code level changes in our app.